# Trying to plot a spiral, just draws a line

Tags: ios, uiview, spiral

I am trying to plot a spiral in a `UIView` just using text labels. Code is below:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  spiral
//
//  Created on 30/01/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015  All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *canvas;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //[self plotPoints:self.view.frame.size.width/2 andY:self.view.frame.size.height/2];

    // centerX-- X origin of the spiral.
    // centerY-- Y origin of the spiral.
    // radius--- Distance from origin to outer arm.
    // sides---- Number of points or sides along the spiral's arm.
    // coils---- Number of coils or full rotations. (Positive numbers spin clockwise, negative numbers spin counter-clockwise)
    // rotation- Overall rotation of the spiral. ('0'=no rotation, '1'=360 degrees, '180/360'=180 degrees)
    //

    [self spiral:170 andY:284 andRadius:100 withSides:20 andCoils:10 andRotation:0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) spiral: (float)centerX andY:(float)centerY andRadius:(float)radius withSides: (float)sides andCoils:(float)coils andRotation:(float)rotation
{
    //
    // How far to step away from center for each side.
    float awayStep = radius/sides;
    //
    // How far to rotate around center for each side.
    float aroundStep = coils/sides;// 0 to 1 based.
    //
    // Convert aroundStep to radians.
    float aroundRadians = aroundStep * 2 * M_PI;
    //
    // Convert rotation to radians.
    rotation *= 2 * M_PI;
    //
    // For every side, step around and away from center.
    for(int i=1; i<=sides; i++){

        //
        // How far away from center
        float away = i * awayStep;
        //
        // How far around the center.
        float around = i * aroundRadians + rotation;
        //
        // Convert 'around' and 'away' to X and Y.
        float x = centerX + cos(around) * away;
        float y = centerY + sin(around) * away;
        //


        [self plotPoints:x andY:y];
    }
}


-(void)plotPoints: (float)x andY:(float) y {

    UILabel *point = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];

    point.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:19];

    point.text=@"*";
    point.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [self.canvas addSubview:point];
    point.hidden=NO;

}

@end
```

screenshot is below:
[image: screenshot]

Not sure why it's doing this. Is it okay to use float values all the way through the code? Maybe I'm losing something in the trig. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit: looked at the x,y values:

```
2015-01-31 00:02:32.073 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 165.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.075 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 180.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.076 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 155.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.076 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 190.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.077 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 145.000000, y:283.999969
2015-01-31 00:02:32.077 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 200.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.078 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 135.000000, y:283.999939
2015-01-31 00:02:32.078 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 210.000000, y:284.000031
2015-01-31 00:02:32.079 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 125.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.079 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 220.000000, y:284.000061
2015-01-31 00:02:32.080 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 115.000000, y:283.999847
2015-01-31 00:02:32.080 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 230.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.081 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 105.000000, y:283.999908
2015-01-31 00:02:32.081 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 240.000000, y:284.000183
2015-01-31 00:02:32.081 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 95.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.082 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 250.000000, y:284.000122
2015-01-31 00:02:32.160 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 85.000000, y:283.999786
2015-01-31 00:02:32.160 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 260.000000, y:284.000000
2015-01-31 00:02:32.161 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 75.000000, y:283.999878
2015-01-31 00:02:32.161 spiral[86741:6997860] x: 270.000000, y:284.000275
```

seems like the y value isn't computing correctly..

fixed image:

[image: fixed!]

Comment: Have you inspected the `x` and `y` values passed in to `plotPoints:andY:`? Are they what you expect? If not, have you set a breakpoint in `spiral:…` and stepped through the code with the debugger to see where the values change from what you expect?

Comment: good idea, just posted these now. seems like a problem with the y values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are entering your angles in degress, the proper conversion to radians is:

```
float radians = degrees * M_PI / 180.0f;
```

Your input to the function appears to be wrong, too.

```
float aroundStep = coils/sides;// 0 to 1 based.
```

This comment suggests that `coils` < `sides`. You have entered `10` and `5`, making `aroundStep = 2`; not between `0` and `1`.

Comment: yeh just noticed the sides and coils thing, changed it to 10/20. Having a look at the angles now

Comment: the code is already converting into radians. the coil and side rotation change made no difference either

Comment: The code *claims* to convert to radians using `float aroundRadians = aroundStep * 2 * M_PI;`. This is not a conversion to radians, though.

Comment: that fixed it with these parameters [self spiral:170 andY:284 andRadius:100 withSides:100 andCoils:1000 andRotation:1];

Comment: float aroundStep = coils/sides;// actually this doesn't have to be 0 to 1 based. error in code

Comment: all done! included a screenshot in the edit of the spiral. thanks for your help !

Comment: Incidentally, you could use the `around` value to rotate your images so they always point in or `away` to scale them so they get bigger as they go out. It's unrelated to your question, but I thought you might like to know.